# Using Animate[] statically

Tags: dynamic, animation

How can I have Animate[] create an animation only with the current instances of assigned variables, and then not update dynamically when they are changed later? For instance, if my code were

```
f[x_]:=x^2
Animate[Plot[f[a - x], {x, -1, 1}], {a, 0, 2}]
f[x_]:=x^3
```

it is going to overwrite the animation based on x^2 with the animation based on x^3. Is there an easy way to stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `Animate` independent of `f`.  How do you do that?

### Quick and dirty

A non-robust way, which works in this case, would be:

```
Module[{ff, xx},
 ff = f[xx];
 Animate[Plot[ff /. xx -> a - x, {x, -1, 1}], {a, 0, 2}]
 ]
```

This is unaffected by future redefinitions of `f`, and works in this this case.  Note, however, that this relies upon `f[xx]` evaluating to something that is both (1) independent of future redefinitions* and (2) the same, upon replacement, as supplying `f[a-x]` directly.  In particular, this would fail if `f` were initially defined as follows:

```
ClearAll[f]
(* f[xx] won't evaluate until xx is replaced with a real number *)
f[x_] /; x > 1 := x^2
f[x_] /; x < 1 := x
```

or

```
ClearAll[f]
(* f[xx] will evaluate differently than f[aRealNumber] *)
f[x_Real] := x^2
f[x_] := x
```

<sub>*Even here you could later do something silly like `Unprotect[Power]; Power[x_,y__]:=x` to mess things up, though I think it's reasonable to assume you're not worried about that.</sub>

### More robust

```
Module[{ff},
 DownValues[ff] = (DownValues[f] /. f -> ff);
 Animate[Plot[ff[a - x], {x, -1, 1}], {a, 0, 2}]
 ]
```

Here you've effectively copied the definition of `f` into `ff`.

Comment: Use `DynamicModule` and it will even survive across sessions.